# le cas d'absence d'article vs. le cas de l'absence de l'article

Tags: absence-d-article

> le cas d'absence d'article

Pourquoi on ne dit pas:

> le cas de l'absence de l'article?

Comment: Probablement parce que la phrase parle d'article en général plutôt que d'un article en particulier. Par exemple si une structure grammaticale implique l'utlisation d'un unique article, la deuxième forme serait utilisée.

Comment: @vc74 Pourriez-vous me donner des exemples?

Comment: Hello @Damian, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your answers.

Comment: I beg your pardon?

Answer (score 5):

C'est la difference entre les articles définis (le) and indéfinis (un):

• de (d') est indéfini (on parle d'une absence ou d'un article en général)

• du (de l') est défini (on parle de l'absence ou de l'article qui est connu - en général parce qu'on en a parlé plus tôt dans la conversation).

Exemples:

> Un enfant a besoin d'amour pour s'épanouir.
>
> Un enfant a besoin de l'amour de sa mère pour s'épanouir.